# How to configure web security in spring security to allow some url to access?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-rest, spring-oauth2

How to configure WebSecurity in java based to allow some urls to be accessed. i tried as below

```
@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeUrls()
        .antMatchers("/rest/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN");            
  }
```

Here on above i want to allow "/rest/**"  **to all (it means this url should not be under security) and  "/admin**/**" should be secured and have authority of Admin. FYI i am using this with Spring oauth too so "/oauth/token" also should be accessible to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to make all urls that you need open by admin scope:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
```

I think you do not need to specify urls that are not have access permission in your configure method because they will be accessed normally.

Comment: @Dias what if i want `/admin/termsAndCondition` to be public?